# How do I Change image size using flux slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flux

I want to use [flux slider](https://github.com/joelambert/Flux-Slider) for the website I am building... Everything works fine except that I am not able to change Image size... I have tried the following jquery

```
$(function(){

if(!flux.browser.supportsTransitions)
 alert("Flux Slider requires a browser that supports CSS3 transitions");

window.f = new flux.slider('#slider', {
pagination: true,
width: 300,
height: 300,
transitions: ['bars3d']

});

});
```

but this crops the image to the size i specify insted of scaling.
is there any solution? please help.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the height to 0 and setting your width to negative should do it.

```
$(function(){
    if(!flux.browser.supportsTransitions)
        alert("Flux Slider requires a browser that supports CSS3 transitions");
    window.f = new flux.slider('#slider', {
        pagination: true,
        width: -300,
        height: 0,
        transitions: ['bars3d']
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three possible problems (not sure as you not added html/css r fiddle);

1) You are resizing image container where as you have set `height` and `width` to images as well e.g. `<img src="blahblah.jgp" height="900" width="500" />` removing `height/width` will fix the issue.

2) Secondly, check if you some css not making js to override i.e. you areusing `!important` with images css (height/width) applied on images.

3) Last but not the least, try this in addition setting images container `height/width` through js that you are already doing, this will make images to automatically fit to their container.

```
img{
    max-width: 100% !important;
    height:auto 100% !important;
    display:block 100% !important;
}
```

Also try adding !important with your js too. hopefully any of them will work for you.

good luck